# Python split a tuple into individual parts...getpixel(rgb)

Tags: python

I'm trying to grab the color palette from an image to reuse once I have combined multiple images, with the same color palette together.  I can get use `getcolor` and get the list that shows how many times each color was used and what the RGB make up of the color was.  How I do take the list and pull off each 'r', 'g', 'b' value so I can create a new image palette with the same color code.  I can reset the palette once I have the rgb values.  I just need those values.

[(531266, (255, 123, 0)] obviously the 531266 is the number of times the color showed up, the 255 is the red value, 123 is the green value and 0 is the blue value.  How do I grab it with code though.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uuhh... Guessing here that you want to access the individual colors?

```
# Let's assume that 'a' contains your values
a = [(531266, (255, 123, 0))]
times, (r, g, b) = a[0]
```

Note: that's just a "fancy" way to do it. You could just extract every element separately using indexing, but it's most useful when looping:

```
for times, (r, g, b) in im.getcolors():
    # do something
```

Comment: Note that the the list OP posted has unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Mmh... true, `getcolors` gives a list of `(count, color)`

Comment: In addition to indexing `a`, you can do: `(times, (r, g, b)), = a`

Comment: @iCodez true in my example, but I'm expecting the general case of `getcolors` to return more than 1 element in the list :P

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to do.  I couldn't figure that one to save my soul.  I love the simplicity of Python compared to what I use to have to deal with in VB6.  Thanks

Comment: Okay, that should make it even easier.  I was figuring it might be interesting to try to pull off the whole list(23 color codes) and I believe that should take care of the problem.